# How to control the rotation of rive animation from flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, rive

So I have a rive animation , and i want to rotate the legs of the animation to a certain degree using inputs from my flutter application.
For example in the application if the user selects 60 degree , then the animation's legs should also move 60 degree

[image: This is the idle state]

[image: And the animation should respond by changing the leg movement by the angle specified by the application]

Comment: Could you have different scenes in your rive file for the different rotations?  https://pub.dev/packages/rive#examples

Comment: I dont know what do you mean by different scenes but , i have achieved what i wanted , Basically i used blend mode and 3 layes , 1 main layer and 2 layers for each leg movement